# A Pointless Endeavor

Tags: knowledge, pattern

I found an box of weird junk in my Grandmother's storage closet earlier this week.  It included:

> - A tin can, painted green
> - Another can, this one an old store-brand Diet Root Beer can in light brown
> - A burned CD-ROM: orange marker indicates it contains a copy of *Second Life*
> - In a tiny baggie, a pink pill that I *think* is MDMA
> - A light blue gram weight from one of those calibration sets

There was a sixth item in there, a tiny bottle, but I fumbled it and it fell into a dark corner with the sound of shattering glass before I could get a good look at it.

Honestly, I was ready to throw the whole box out (my grandmother doesn't even *have* a PC with a CD-ROM drive, and the less thought about the club drug the better), but when I mentioned it to my grandmother, she said that it was a "silly little collection" of hers.  Now I feel sort of bad that my clumsiness broke up the collection.  I'd like to replace the last object, but I'd really like to not mention that I broke something of my grandmother's before I have the replacement in hand.  So...

**What do I need to complete the collection?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps the last bottle was

> A yellow bottle containing hydrogen

Reasoning

> Your grandmother likes to collect things which have colours and initials corresponding to the categories in [Trivial Pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit)
>  **A green tin can**
>  Tin has the chemical symbol **Sn** and the green category in Trivial Pursuit is **S**cience and **N**ature.
>  **Another can, this one an old store-brand Diet Root Beer can in light brown**
>  I think this refers to **A&W** diet root beer. The brown category in Trivial Pursuit is **A**rts & **W**riting (Arts & Literature).
>  **A burned CD-ROM: orange marker indicates it contains a copy of Second Life**.
>  Presumably the CD would be marked **SL** and the orange category in Trivial Pursuit is **S**port and **L**eisure.
>  **In a tiny baggie, a pink pill that I think is MDMA**
>  MDMA is also known as ectasy or **e** and the pink category in Trivial Pursuit is **E**ntertainment.
>  **A light blue gram weight from one of those calibration sets**.
>  Presumably, this would just have **g** written on it and the light blue category in Trivial Pursuit is **G**eography.
>  The final category is the yellow **H**istory category so your grandmother would need something yellow with a **H** on it (hydrogen works but it could also be heroin).

Title

> "Pointless Endeavour" is a synonym for "Trivial Pursuit"

Comment: Sounds about right!  V oryvrir gung gur fbqn pna vf na nyhzvahz pna, juvpu vf zber qverpgyl N naq Y guna gur ebbg orre glcr, ohg V qvq artyrpg gb zragvba gung qrgnvy.